# Why am I getting a different HTML response with AsyncTask compared to eclipse?

Tags: java, android, html, eclipse, android-asynctask

When I make a get request to the given website in eclipse with the following code:

```
public String getLink(){
    vidLink = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=paradise+city+guns+n+roses+audio+only";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(vidLink);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        Scanner s = new Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A");
        result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("error");
```

I get the response (STORED IN VARIABLE RESULT)

```
<li><div class="yt-lockup yt-lockup-tile yt-lockup-video vve-check clearfix" data-context-item-id="CutFtFcZLrA"
```

(WHICH IS WHAT I WANT)

However, when I make the same get request in android studio using async task, with the following code:

```
    public class HttpGetRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    String result;
    String inputLine;
    String sname = "hello";
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        try {
            String stringUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=paradise+city+guns+n+roses+audio+only";
            URL myUrl = new URL(stringUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)
                    myUrl.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
            connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            Scanner s = new Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A");
            result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";

            linkloc = result.indexOf(testString) + testString.length();
            for(int i = linkloc; result.charAt(i) != ('\"'); i++){
                sname += result.charAt(i) + "";
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            sname = "Error";
        }


        return result;
    }
```

I get the response (STORED IN VARIABLE RESULT) something along the lines of:       <    !DOCTYPE html>      @font-fac etc....

What difference is there between the two requests, and how can I fix the android studio response to get the response in eclipse? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is `connection.setRequestProperty("text/html","charset=utf-8")` for? Your usage of `HttpURLConnection` is very different... I think it may have less to do with `AsyncTask` and more to do with constructing the HTTP request differently.

Comment: In the first example you're processing the response using a `Scanner` and in the second one you're just reading the entire response and storing it in a `String`. If you want the same result, do the same thing. Just wrap the `HttpURLConnection` input stream in a `Scanner`, set the delimiter and read the first token.

Comment: @Kekoa Just removed... still getting the same response

Comment: @Titus just switched to the scanner that I used in eclipse, but I am still getting the same response. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you edit your question to illustrate the changes that you've made ?

Comment: @Titus I have changed it